# how to set hover effect (NOTE: ONLY THE SQUARE BORDER SHOULD ROTATE LIKE DIAMOND SHAPE WHEN HOVERING, NOT THE IMAGE)

Tags: html, css, hover

[THIS IS THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFJoU.png)

The border should rotate like a diamond shape but the image inside the div element should not rotate. I have attached the image and code. Please go through and help me out.

For me, the image is also rotating.

```
<!--HTML CODE-->
 <div class="section-1">
  <div class="support-sec-img">
   <img src="images\free-support.png" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>


/* CSS CODE */
.support-sec-img { 
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; 
    width: 73px; 
    height: 73px; 
    margin: auto; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center; 
}

.section-1:hover .support-sec-img  { 
    transform: rotate(-45deg); 
    border: 1px solid #e95c4e;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the img with an svg but the system is simply. If you rotate the box counterclockwise you have to rotate the icon back clockwise.

```css
.support-sec-img { 
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; 
    width: 73px; 
    height: 73px; 
    margin: auto; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center; 
}

.section-1:hover .support-sec-img  { 
    transform: rotate(-45deg); 
    border: 1px solid #e95c4e;
}

.section-1:hover .support-sec-img svg { 
    transform: rotate(45deg); 
}
```

```html
 <div class="section-1">
  <div class="support-sec-img">
   <svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"><path d="M12 21.593c-5.63-5.539-11-10.297-11-14.402 0-3.791 3.068-5.191 5.281-5.191 1.312 0 4.151.501 5.719 4.457 1.59-3.968 4.464-4.447 5.726-4.447 2.54 0 5.274 1.621 5.274 5.181 0 4.069-5.136 8.625-11 14.402m5.726-20.583c-2.203 0-4.446 1.042-5.726 3.238-1.285-2.206-3.522-3.248-5.719-3.248-3.183 0-6.281 2.187-6.281 6.191 0 4.661 5.571 9.429 12 15.809 6.43-6.38 12-11.148 12-15.809 0-4.011-3.095-6.181-6.274-6.181"/></svg>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: wow man, thanks a lot :) this was perfect